# Resume bib item numbering with multibbl

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, subdividing

I am using multibbl package to create separated bibliographies for my CV (e.g., to separate journal and conference publications). It works really well, however it resets the bibliography item numbers for each bibliography.

For example, if I use:

```
\newbibliography{journal}
\bibliographystyle{journal}{../bib/plainyr-rev}
\nocite{journal}{*}
\bibliography{journal}{../bib/journal}{\large \textsc{Refereed Journal Articles}}
```

and use

```
\newbibliography{conference}
\bibliographystyle{journal}{../bib/plainyr-rev}
\nocite{conference}{*}
\bibliography{conference}{../bib/conference}{\large \textsc{Refereed Conference Publications}}
```

then I get an output similar to the following:

```
Refereed Journal Articles

[1] Author name. Title. Some Journal, 2013.

Refereed Conference Publications

[1] Author name. Title. In Some conference, address, 2013.
```

Instead what I really want (wish) is that the numbering resumes from where it left, something along the lines...

```
Refereed Journal Articles

[1] Author name. Title. Some Journal, 2013.

Refereed Conference Publications

[2] Author name. Title. In Some conference, address, 2013.
```

Is this possible? Thanks,

Edit: Working example

Content for example.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}

\begin{document}

\newbibliography{journal}
\bibliographystyle{journal}{plain}
\nocite{journal}{*}
\bibliography{journal}{journal}
{\large \textsc{Refereed Journal Articles}}

\newbibliography{conference}
\nocite{conference}{*}
\bibliographystyle{conference}{plain}
\bibliography{conference}{conference}
{\large \textsc{Refereed Conference Publications}}

\end{document}
```

content for journal.bib

```
@article{entry2,
    author = {Author name},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    title = {Title},
    year = {2013},
}
```

content for conference.bib

```
@inproceedings{entry1,
    author = {Author name},
    address = {address},
    booktitle = {Some conference},
    title = {Title},
    year = {2013},
}
```

Just invoke:

```
pdflatex.exe example.tex
bibtex.exe conference
bibtex.exe journal
pdflatex.exe example.tex
```

to get the undesired output :)

Comment: How are you loading the package? Is it like `\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}`? If so, get rid of `resetlabels`. Also, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Also, making your code a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (*i.e.*, complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`) will mean that you get better help quicker on this site.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you were using `multibib`, not `multibbl`. The default behavior in `multibib` is continuous numbering. I'm not familiar with `multibbl`, so someone else will have to help.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, I am using multibbl. If transition to multibib is seamless, I might try that. Is it similar?

Also, updated the example with MWE.

Comment: [This](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib) compares the two packages; hope that helps.

Comment: @Adam: Worked beautifully. The transition was quite painless, too.
Just a quick follow-up. Is there a way to indent the numbering created for the different bibliographies. For example, one of my bibliographies have more than 10 elements, so multibib indents it automatically. However, this makes the indenting of the previous bibliography (which starts and ends before '10') inconsistent.

Comment: Glad to hear it! You may wish to consider answering your own question, then, with an MWE that shows your approach with `multibib`. Perhaps someone will also provide an answer that uses `multibbl`. In any event, I imagine that having both answers to the question might be helpful to future visitors on this site.

Comment: Very good idea, I am on it :)
I was searching a way to give you +rep, but I guess I cannot do that for comments.

Comment: By the way, turns out that due to my reputation, I cannot answer my own question before 8 hours pass. I will update it tomorrow (if the system permits).

Comment: [The system should permit it.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Adam, I managed to use multibib, which does what I was looking for by default.

Here is the updated MWE that lists the publications in resumed numbering:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{journal,conference}{Refereed Journal Articles, Refereed Conference Publications}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystylejournal{plain}
\nocitejournal{*}
\bibliographyjournal{journal}

\bibliographystyleconference{plain}
\nociteconference{*}
\bibliographyconference{conference}

\end{document}
```

The example uses the same .bib files in the original post and produces the following result (as expected):

```
Refereed Journal Articles

[1] Author name. Title. Some Journal, 2013.

Refereed Conference Publications

[2] Author name. Title. In Some conference, address, 2013.
```